What should we do for the tag wiki of [pre] tag?
We have a pre tag on this site.
This tag was previously used in this question: What is a pre vote? , but a user deleted this tag and mentioned that this tag does lack a tag wiki. (see here)
I have seen the questions of this tag, but I still have no ideas what should we write for the tag wiki (or the excerpt) of this tag.
The questions are not the topic I familiar with.
So, should we clarify the tag clearly?

I went ahead and performed a merge here in accordance with Glorfindel's suggestion. pre is now mapped to code-formatting.
I did a spot-check and all 15 questions that were tagged with it were good candidates for code-formatting, and none of them really fit closure/deletion criteria, so this looks like Mission Accomplished.

I don't think we need this tag. We should burninate it.
All of the posts currently tagged with pre seem to be talking about <pre> blocks, which are another way you can format code on SE.
Everything that you could tag with pre could be adequately localized to the markdown tag and/or the code-formatting or the code-block tag. Speaking of which, we should consider merging the latter into the former, or vice versa, whatever makes the most sense. That's outside of the scope of this discussion, but worth mentioning.
We shouldn't need to have tags that are subsets of other tags, especially when they're ambiguous like this. We should consolidate where we can, and this is a place where we should.

[tag:code-formatting] is probably for both inline code (delimited with single backticks) and code blocks (delimited with triple backticks or four spaces). So [tag:code-block] is a subset of [tag:code-formatting]. Whether it's worth making a distinction (and if the involved questions are properly tagged), that's up to debate :)

Fair enough :-)

Strictly-speaking, <pre> is for any preformatted passage. (The classic example is poetry.) <pre><code> is a special-case.

My 2 cents: let's merge it into code-formatting. That's its purpose and that's not clear to anybody except web developers. It's probably the only HTML tag with its own tag here. No, meta does not count ...
